# pass outer scope logic to a callback function javascript nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

/file_iterator.js

```
var asyncFileObjectReader = require('../core/async_forEach_Array.js')
var sampleFunction;

function allAcitemFileIterator(filesObject, mapContainer, root_directory) {     

    asyncFileObjectReader.forEachFunction(filesObject, sampleFunction);

    sampleFunction = function (fileName) {
        mapContainer.set(basePathAlterColons.removeBasePathAlterColons(fileName, root_directory), 
            extractUriFromList.extractUriFromList(getReferences.getReferences(fileName)));
    }
}
```

/async_foreach_Array.js

```
function forEachFunction(filesObject, filesObjectFunction) {
    filesObject.forEach(function (fileName) {
        if (path.extname(fileName) === acitem_file_extension) {
            filesObjectFunction(fileName);
        }
    });
}
```

When I try to pass the sampleFunction as a callback function to the forEachFunction, but still maintaining the state of the outer function, I am getting an error as "undefined as not a function" Pls help ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the function before you define it! Swap those two statements:

```
sampleFunction = function (fileName) {
    mapContainer.set(basePathAlterColons.removeBasePathAlterColons(fileName, root_directory), 
        extractUriFromList.extractUriFromList(getReferences.getReferences(fileName)));
};

asyncFileObjectReader.forEachFunction(filesObject, sampleFunction);
```

Oh, and there's really no reason to make `sampleFunction` global to your module. Especially as you use `mapContainer` and `root_directory` as closure variables, in an async function. This would lead to horrible race conditions if `allAcitemFileIterator` is called too fast. So please use `var sampleFunction = …`, or just a function declaration.

Comment: OMG, Thank you  Bergi, my function worked like a charm. You saved my day. Once again thank you and have a great day.